# PHP: Remove folders and files in them but keep main directory

Tags: php

I have a directory `/main` with folders and files inside those folders.

I want to keep directory /main but delete everything in it:

```
$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/main');

foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {
    if(!is_dir($filename)){
        unlink($filename);      
    }
};
```

This is deleting the files inside the folders, leaving `/main` with a list of empty folders, how do I delete these now?

I know this should be possible to integrate inside the loop, I tried `rmdir` without success.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

### UPDATED ANSWER:

```
$dir = '/home/XXXXX/public_html/';
foreach(glob($dir.'*.*') as $v){

echo $v;
  //  unlink($v);
}



destroy_dir($dir);
function destroy_dir($dir) { 
    if (!is_dir($dir) || is_link($dir)) return unlink($dir); 
        foreach (scandir($dir) as $file) { 
            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue; 
            if (!destroy_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file)) { 
                chmod($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file, 0777); 
                if (!destroy_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file)) return false; 
            }; 
        } 
        return rmdir($dir); 
    }
```

Here, Code is not tested.

Comment: I get: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function destroy_dir()

Comment: Thanks, it isn't echoeing anything on the 1st block of code but it does remove all folders and files, including /main which wasn't supposed to happen

Answer (score 0):

```
function delete_directory_files($dirname)  {
  if (is_dir($dirname))
      $dir_handle = opendir($dirname);
   if (!$dir_handle)
      return false;
   while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
         if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file))
            unlink($dirname."/".$file);
         else
            delete_directory($dirname.'/'.$file);    
      }
   }
   closedir($dir_handle);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried that: http://www.paulund.co.uk/php-delete-directory-and-files-in-directory